# node.js sheets.spreadsheets.values.get assign value in variable

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I have a problem. I have assigned a result in arrayName.
In the first console.log it is not empty, but in the second console log, it is undefined.

```
function getData(auth) {
  var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
  var arrayName= [];
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    auth: auth,
    spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    range: 'b2:b99', 
  }, (err, response) => {
    var rows = response.values;
    if (rows.length != 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        arrayName.push(row[0]);
        }
       console.log(arrayName);
     }
  });
  console.log(arrayName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

Your second `console.log()` is out of scope. Set an empty variable *before* you enter the `sheets.spreadsheet.values.get()` function so you have the value *outside* of the function.

### Example

**Try this:**

```
function getData(auth) {

  var log = "";                //<---- Create an empty variable

  var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
  var arrayName= [];
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    auth: auth,
    spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    range: 'b2:b99', 
  }, (err, response) => {
    var rows = response.values;
    if (rows.length != 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        arrayName.push(row[0]);
        }
       log = arrayName;         //<---- Store your value within the function
       console.log(arrayName);
     }
  });
  console.log(log);            //<---- Recall the value outside the function
}
```